# getting response of ajax made from previous page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have two pages A.html and B.html. For A I will make Ajax request to a server using jQuery, long task would run and data would be received in the success callback function. But I would navigate to B after the Ajax request. I want to have response to display on page B. Please help me to design a solution for it. Thank you

Comment: That would require the server side code to be in on the act - as you've provided no information about the server side (server, language, platform) it's not possible to even know if what you want to do can be handled by the server

Answer (score 0):

You could just redirect the user to `B.html` and send the data as a url parameter.

On `A.html`:

```
function callback(data) {
    //run code to check to make sure the data is valid, and stuff like that


   //then redirect the user to B.html with the data as a URL parameter
   window.location.href = "/B.html?data=" + encodeCallbackData(data);
}
```

You would need to implement the `encodeCallbackData()` function.
If the response type is JSON, it might look like this:

```
function encodeCallbackData(data) {
    return encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

then, on `B.html`

```
if (getParameterByName("data") !== null) {
    var json = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(getParameterByName("data")));
    // json is a variable containing the object resulting from the AJAX request.
    //do something with json
    //show the success message.
} else {
    //the user was not redirected from `A.html`.
}
```

`getParameterByName` can be found on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript/901144#901144) stack overflow answer.

Comment: I will be already in page B where I want to display response from callback function which is defined in A.